# How do I use the LilyPond in Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to use the LilyPond to generate music notations. So I want to use it in Java Netbeans. But I'm unable to get the .ly extension file type in java netbeans. How do I connect the LilyPond with netbeans? Please could you mention the steps that I have to follow to do this? Thanks in advance.[LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/)